# controlar llamadas simultaneas a un servicio REST sin que se duplique la ID en JAVA

Tags: java, spring, rest, jmeter

estoy haciendo un servicio REST a través de Spring y swagger con protocolo CMIS. mis servicio funciona bien hasta el momento que hago llamadas simultaneas a través de Jmeter para poder estresar el sistema. 
Contexto:
el servicio obtiene la ID desde un creador de ID para generar el nodo. La id no se puede repetir en el sistema y este toma el último nodo creado y le suma 1. Intenté con Thread.sleep y con TimeUnit. El jmeter arroja que se crea el primero y el 3ro con la misma id y las otras 8 respuestas fueron que la id existe, por ende no crea otra id como debiese ser ni crea ortos nodos.

extracto de código actual:
Controladora

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Crea un Tipo de documento")
@RequestMapping(value = "/create2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseMessage createTypeDocument2(@RequestParam String description) throws InterruptedException {     
    int id = typeDocumentService.idCreator2();
    return typeDocumentService.createTypeDocument(id,description);
}
```

Servicio

```
public ResponseMessage createTypeDocument(int id, String description) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(1000);     
    Session session = obtieneSesion();      
    ResponseMessage rm = new ResponseMessage();     
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);      
    if(searchDocuments(id)==null ) {        
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("SSS");
        Date date = new Date();
        String nombre = sdf.format(date.getTime());                 
        DocumentTypeDTO docFilter = new DocumentTypeDTO();
        Folder root = (Folder) session.getObjectByPath("/DataList-BCH");            
        HashMap<String, Object> metadata = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        metadata.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "********");
        metadata.put(PropertyIds.NAME, nombre); 
        Document newDoc = root.createDocument(metadata, null, null);            
        docFilter.setId( Integer.parseInt(newDoc.getProperty("bc:id").getValueAsString()));
        docFilter.setDescription(newDoc.getProperty("bc:description").getValueAsString());
        docFilter.setUuid(newDoc.getId().replaceAll(";1.0", "").replace("workspace://SpacesStore/", ""));   

        rm.setMensaje("Exitoso");
        rm.setCodigo(200);
        rm.setObjeto(docFilter);
        return rm;
    }else {
        rm.setCodigo(-1);
        rm.setMensaje("La ID ya existe");
        return rm;
    }       
}
```

el método de searchDocument si no encuentro el objeto con esa id retorna null, por ende crea el nodo nuevo y el nuevo DTO.

ya e intentado varias opciones sin resultado, por eso requiero de su ayuda para poder resolverlo.
de antemano muchas gracias

EDIT: idCreator2(); obviamente tengo otro creador de id's pero creo que este funciona mejor

```
private int idCreator2() {          

    Session session = obtieneSesion();
    String queryString = "select * from bc:baseListData";           
    List<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>();    
    int id=1;
    ItemIterable<QueryResult> results = session.query(queryString, false);
    for (QueryResult qResult : results) {
        String objectId = "";
        PropertyData<?> propData = qResult.getPropertyById("cmis:objectId");
        if (propData != null) {
            objectId = (String) propData.getFirstValue();
        } else {
            objectId = qResult.getPropertyValueByQueryName("d.cmis:objectId");
        }
        CmisObject obj = session.getObject(session.createObjectId(objectId));
        idList.add(Integer.parseInt(obj.getPropertyValue("bc:id").toString()));         
    }       
    Collections.sort(idList);
    if (!idList.isEmpty()){
        id = idList.get(idList.size()-1)+1;
    }

    return id;
}
```

Comment: cual es el codigo de `typeDocumentService.idCreator2()`?

Comment: @Klaimmore edité mi pregunta para que lo veas. Asi mismo te comento que funciona si en el restlet client o postman hago una llamada simple. pero no en una llamada simultanea en jmeter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No creo que agregando una transacción soluciones tu problema.

Podrías declarar un metodo `synchronized` que se encargue de crear el id y el documento. Efectivamente bloqueando todos los *threads* que intenten crear los id's en simultaneo, asumiendo que `TypeDocumentService` es `Singleton` (por defecto, en spring):

```
public synchronized ResponseMessage crearDocumento(String description) {
    int id = this.idCreator2();
    return this.createTypeDocument(id,description);
}
```

Pero esta solucion es frágil, solo funcionará para que tu aplicación en particular no cree id's duplicados.

De forma concurrente podrían modificar tu repositorio directamente por otra vía y duplicar dichos id's siguiendo una lógica similar a la que estás usando para la creación.

---

Yo te recomendaria seguir una estrategia de creacion de id distinta, por ejemplo con [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier):

```
String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Este identificador para todos los fines practicos es unico. Citado desde la entrada en wikipedia:

> Thus, for there to be a one in a billion chance of duplication, 103
>   trillion version 4 UUIDs must be generated.

Comment: si, lo consideré lo del random uuid. pero por regla de más arriba no puedo. intenté con Zynchronized, y casi funciona, crea 4 elementos con la misma id, 2 reconocen que el id existe y otros 4 elementos con otro id

Comment: Tienes razón, la obtención de la id y la creación del documento deben estar bajo el mismo metodo `synchronized`

Comment: Amigo si pudiese abrazarte lo haría. eres Dios

Comment: Al final era unir ambas respuestas, me alegro de que lo hayas solucionado

Answer (score 0):

Hay motivos por los que creo que deberías cambiar la forma en que guardas un nuevo elemento:

1. El `@Controller` no necesita saber cómo funciona tu lógica, sólo lo que hace. Una llamada al servicio debería ser suficiente.
2. Un método del `@Service` puede contener una única transacción, con lo que te aseguras la atomicidad. Si tienes dos llamadas, tienes dos transacciones, con lo que es posible que dos o más hilos llamen al método `idCreator2` consecutivamente, antes de que el otro guarde nada. En ese caso te encontrarás IDs repetidas.

Mi consejo: Una única llamada al service y que él se encargue de todo

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Crea un Tipo de documento")
@RequestMapping(value = "/create2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseMessage createTypeDocument2(@RequestParam String description) throws InterruptedException {     

    return typeDocumentService.createTypeDocument(description);
}
```

y en el servicio:

```
public ResponseMessage createTypeDocument(String description) throws InterruptedException {

    int id = this.idCreator2(); //método privado!!!

    ... //resto del código

}
```

**Nota:** Parece que La anotación de Spring `@Transaction` no funciona con Alfresco (supongo que no detectará los recursos sobre los que hacer el *lock*), sino que este usa su propio [gestor](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/AlfrescoOne/5.1/PublicAPI/org/alfresco/repo/transaction/RetryingTransactionHelper.html) de [transacciones](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/dev-extension-points-public-java-api.html)

Comment: no existe ese tag en mi ambiente de desarrollo, debo importar alguna dependencia mas nueva?? (uso MAVEN)

Comment: Está en [spring-tx](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx)

Comment: hice la prueba en jmeter 10 consultas en un seg. se crearon los 10 nodos en alfresco con la misma ID

Comment: agregué mi metodo idCreator en la pregunta por si lo necesitas revisar de nuevo

Comment: Estoy viendo que Alfresco tiene su propio sistema de transacciones, pero no encuentro mucha información sobre el mismo, ni en inglés ni en español

Comment: si, intenté buscar, mi ultima opción fue preguntar por aquí y en inglés igual, no encuentro respuesta

Comment: Te he añadido un par de enlaces y he quitado lo que no corresponde: La idea general es la misma, pero no conozco Alfresco (nunca lo he tocado) y por tanto no sabría ayudarte

Comment: gracias!! se agradece mucho